# prolog List Reverse

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

```
%reverse_List
reverseList(H|T,ReversedList):-
    reverseListHelper(T,[H],ReversedList).
reverseListHelper([],Accumulator.Accumulator).
reverseListHelper([H|T],Accumulator,ReversedList):-
    reverseListHelper(T,[H|Accumulator],ReversedList).
```

I am beginner to prolog, what wrong with this code ?
it's just giving the output false
kindly explain thanks

I understand the theory of how recursive works in list reversing but not the code much,  if any one could explain line by line would be great thanks

Comment: Three typos. In `Accumulator.Accumulator` use a `,` instead. Then add `[` and `]` around `H|T` in first clause. Add a fact for the empty list,

Answer (score 0):

One can look at a list in Prolog as essentially a *FIFO (first-in/first-out) stack*: you can examine, add or remove things only from the top/head: the remainder of the list is opaque.

Reversal of such a list, then, consists of repeatedly (and recursively) *popping* items from the source stack and *pushing* each such popped item onto a result stack.

And a common idiom in prolog is the use of a helper predicate with the same name, but different *arity*, where the additional argument(s) carry whatever extra state is required to solve the problem. In this case, the extra state needs is a list onto which we can push/prepend things as we go, thus building the result in reverse order.

That leads to an implementation of `reverse_list/2` that looks like this:

```
reverse_list( Xs, Ys ) :- reverse_list( Xs , [] , Ys ) .
```

The helper that does all the work isn't much more complicated. There are just two cases:

- The limiting case, where the source list is the empty list, and
- The general case, where the source list is non-empty

The limiting case is easy: if the source list is exhausted, the accumulator, whatever it might contain, is the reversed list. That gives us

```
reverse_list( [] , Zs, Zs ) .
```

The general case merely involves

- removing the head of the source list,
- prepending it to the accumulator, and
- recursing down on the tails.

Which leads to this (you might note that we leave the final result alone until we hit the limiting case here)

```
reverse( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] , Zs ) :- reverse(Xs,Ys,Zs)
```

Putting it all together, we get

```
% reverse/2 ----------------------------------------------------------
%
% reverse( Source, Reverse )
%
% Simply invoke the helper predicate, seeding the accumulator with the
% empty list.
%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
reverse( Xs , Ys ) :- reverse(Xs,[],Ys) .

% reverse/3 ----------------------------------------------------------
%
% reverse( Source, Accumulator, Reversed )
%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
reverse( []     ,    Zs  , Zs ) .  % source list empty: unify accumulator and result
reverse( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] , Zs ) :- % non-empty source? Put X on the accumulator, and
  reverse(Xs,Ys,Zs) .              % - recurse down on the tails.
```